# Redis, Node.JS and an Unique ID

Tags: node.js, redis

What is the proper way to handle unique identifiers with Node.JS and Redis?  I'm looking to make the switch from MongoDB/Mongoose to Redis.  There I create a Document which gets a _id field.  I can use that in other Documents, to link back to them.   Then I can use findByID() to retrieve the document.

I'd like to accomplish the same thing in Redis.

Comment: Are you looking for information on how to convert an existing MongoDB system over to Redis, or are you asking how one would setup a like system from scratch?

Comment: Looking to rebuild from scratch. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For simplicity, let's imagine you have two types of objects in your system: `users` and `widgets`. Each of these objects will be stored in Redis as hashes. Below are the fields that each of the object types will have in their hashes:

1. user

   - id
   - name
   - parent (which user is responsible for this user in the system)
2. widget

   - id
   - name
   - owner (which user owns this widget)

The parent field of user and the owner field of widget will act like foreign keys that reference some other object by that object's ID.

With this configuration, you need a couple of other keys in your system: user:id and widget:id. These will be used as auto increment values of the user and widget IDs. Whenever new user or widget is added to the system, you will run the [`INCR`](http://redis.io/commands/incr) command:

```
INCR user:id     # new user ID
INCR widget:id   # new widget ID
```

You will then use the returned `INCR` value as the primary key for the object. Here is some pseudo-code for adding a new user:

```
var newUserId = redis('INCR')
var newUserKey = 'user:' + newUserId

redis('HMSET', [newUserKey,
    'id', newUserId,
    'name', username,
    'parent', parentUserId
])
```

You can see how the above code could be tweaked slightly for adding a new widget.

Let's say that someone requests widget #55 from your system. First we will fetch the widget with that ID, then we will fetch the widget's owner by ID. Below is the pseudo-code for this:

```
var widgetId = req.params.id // 55
var widgetKey = 'widget:' + widgetId  
var widgetObject = redis('HGETALL', [widgetKey])

var userKey = 'user:' + widgetObject.owner
var userObject = redis('HGETALL', [userKey])

// Do something with widgetObject and userObject
```